# RegEx for sequence of decimal numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I have a textbox which should accept input in the following format:

[decimal], [decimal]; [decimal], [decimal]; [decimal], [decimal]

For example:

0.01,0.10; 0.20,0.50; 1.00,3.00; 4.00,1000.00

My knowledge of regular expression is very poor. I was able to do that much

```
^([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+))?$
```

But couldn't do much more. So any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is you need to match exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You regular expression can be like (you may have to adjust the spaces as it's not completely clear from your example where they are correct)

Also, the expression will depend on whether the semicolon at the end is:

optional:

```
^(\s?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+;){3}(\s?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+;?)$
```

shouldn't be there:

```
^(\s?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+;){3}(\s?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$
```

required:

```
^(\s?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+;){4}
```

Comment: I need the user to always have to enter the four pairs of decimals.

Comment: Ok, I update the answer then. You may need to adjust the position of spaces (`\s`) though.

Comment: Note that because you have `;?` it will match `0.0,0.00.0,0.00.0,0.00.0,0.0`

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thanks, that's a good comment. I updated my answer and gave options based on how to treat that semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern will match decimal strings:

```
^([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+))?$
```

However, it will not only match a single decimal and will not allow any other characters before or after it. Also, the decimal group is optional, so it allows the entire string empty.

To modify this string to match your input try this:

```
^(([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?),\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)(;\s*|$)){4}$
```

Comment: Hello, this is almost correct. But it allows the user to enter only half of the sequence. For example, entering: 0.01,0.10; is also acceptable. I need the user to always have to enter the four pairs of decimals.

Comment: @Mdb Sorry, you question was a bit confusing because in the fist example you had 3 pairs and in the second you had 4. You can make it work for *n* pairs by replacing the `+` at the end with `{n}`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
(\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+;?)\s*
```

Comment: This doesn't match `.` character.

Comment: This does not match the input I have posted for example.

Comment: Yes, I missed a space after `;` and after `,` don't need space, check my update, please

Answer (score 0):

Below regex definition will match all decimal numbers with ; and , seperator, also deal with end decimal with no seperator

```
((?<DecimalNumber>[-+]?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?)([;,]*))
```

Use for loop in C# for capturing multiple values for the same group

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be very strict and exactly match your example:

```
^(\d+\.\d+\,\d+\.\d+;\s){3}(\d+\.\d+\,\d+\.\d+\s*)
```

If it can be more loose and allow white-spaces:

```
^(\s*\d+\.\d+\s*\,\s*\d+\.\d+\s*;\s*){3}(\s*\d+\s*\.\d+\s*\,\s*\d+\.\d+\s*)
```

This last one also matches

```
0.01, 0.10;  0.20,   0.50; 1.00 ,3.00; 4.00  ,1000.00
```